# Object has no method 'fadeout'

Tags: jquery

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fadeout'

Here's my code:

```
// Fade out the Silhouette and fade in the picture
// when the <h3> Who am I text is clicked
$('div#mysteryPanel > h3').click(function(){
  $('#silhouette').fadeout(5000);
});
```

When the text in an `<h3>` tag is clicked an image is suppose to fade out and another one is suppose to fade in after a delay. Can someone explain to me what I have wrong so that I can fix this error?

This is part of a class assignment, so an explanation of what I have done wrong is preferred.

Comment: Did you read the first line of the question...?

Comment: post your html code as well

Comment: @sachleen No sorry I'm sleepy :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's case sensitive. the function you want is [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Answer (score 1):

You're using an incorrect jquery command.
It's "fadeOut" and not "fadeout"